# Unable to tts = TextToSpeech() | Tortoise tts | Torch

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, text-to-speech, voice-recognition

Am sorry, I may not use apt words for explaining my issue. please help me out.
Running the code in VS code with python.

These are the codes screenshots with errors:

[image: !nvidia-smi]

My setup commands:

```
!nvidia-smi

!pip3 install -U scipy
!git clone https://github.com/neonbjb/tortoise-tts.git
%cd tortoise-tts
!pip3 install -r requirements.txt
!python3 setup.py install
```

My Python code:

```
import torch
import torchaudio
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
import IPython
from tortoise.api import TextToSpeech
from tortoise.utils.audio import load_audio, load_voice, load_voices

tts = TextToSpeech()
```

[image: error while loading TextToSpeech() function]

Comment: Hi Daaris, welcome to Stack Overflow. When including source code and errors, it's better to use Stack Overflow's built-in code formatting option rather than posting images. Images are harder to read and text cannot be copied directly.

Comment: Hi @NicholasObert I have tried to add the code snippets as much as possible is this enough

Comment: To me, this looks like you might have leftover data in your torch configuration.  The problem here is torch, not tortoise.  My guess is if you deleted all of the `torch` imports, the code would work.  That might not help with your overall problem, but it would narrow things.

Comment: @TimRoberts I deleted all the imports related to torch, and re-ran my code. Still the same error persists.

Comment: Since the requirements list contains only 23 modules, try to install them by hand in a fresh environment…but with anaconda, not with pip! In order to let Conda deal with the burden of managing all the dependencies between packages !

Comment: @Myron_Ben4 any tip with python! not familiar with conda